# How to set the checkbox in the first column based on the value in the second column?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm automating a task using Ruby and Watir.

I want to set a checkbox (which is in the first column of a table) based on whether the value in the second column matches my input value. For example, in the following code snippet, the value "brett58" matches my input value so I want to set the checkbox associated with it.

```
<tr class="cuesTableRowOdd">
    <td align="center">
        <input class="content-nogroove" type="checkbox" name="result[1].chked" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" value="7bd67e4d-a59f-0143-3886-22c1d205a5c1" name="result[1].col[0].stringVal">
        <input type="hidden" value="brett58" name="result[1].col[1].stringVal">
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <a class="cuesTextLink" href="userEdit.do?key=7bd67e4d-a59f-0143-3886-22c1d205a5c1">brett58</a>
    </td>
    <td align="left">brett</td>
    <td align="left">lee</td>
    <td align="left"></td>
</tr>
```

But I'm unable to do it. In the above case, the following line serves the purpose (as my input value matches with that it first row):

```
browser.table(:class, "cuesTableBg").checkbox(:name, "result[1].chked").click
```

But it can't be used as the required value might not always be in the first row.

Looping through all the rows is one option but it's inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
browser.table(:class, "cuesTableBg").rows.find{ |row| 
  row.cells[1].text == 'brett58'
}.checkbox.set
```

Basically, this is saying find the first row of the table that has "brett58" in the second column. Then set the first checkbox in that row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both - the code as well as the explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def set_checkbox(row_text_to_match)
  @browser.table(:class, "cuesTableBg").row(:text, /#{Regexp.escape(row_text_to_match)}/).checkbox(:name, "result[1].chked").set
end
```